# Prevent overriding keys in Key-Value datastores

Tags: database, algorithm, datastore

This picture below shows a sequence diagram for two clients storing values into a Key-Value datastore:

[image]

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to prevent overriding keys. The way the applications (Client_A, and Client_B) prevent this is by checking if key exists first before storing.  The issue now is if both clients manage to get the same "does not exist" result, any of the two clients would be able to overwrite the values.

What strategy can be done to be able to prevent such from happening in a database client design?

Comment: Is it an option to use memcached as a locking mechanism to serialize access? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/thhwPzg0O9U/discussion

Comment: Yes, in fact, it's a good option, although it seems Memcached has some weird behavior due to its pure in-memory operation.

Answer (score 0):

A "key-value store", as it's usually defined, doesn't store duplicate keys at all.  If two clients write to the same key, then only one value is stored -- the one from which ever client wrote "latest".

In order to reliably update values in a consistent way (where the new value depends on the old value associated with a key, or even whether or not there was an old value), your key-value store needs to support some kinds of atomic operations other than simple get and set.

Memcache, for example, supports atomic compare-and-set operations that will only set a value if it hasn't been set by someone else since you read it.  Amazon's DynamoDB supports atomic transactions, atomic counters, etc.

Comment: I'm hoping to implement on top of object storage, so DynanoDB is not really an option. Although you're right it needs to be atomic, which most object storages are not.

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
take action depending on result
UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

The "transaction" makes the pair. SELECT and UPDATE, "atomic".

Write this sort of code for any situation where another connection can sneak in and mess up what you are doing.

Note: The code written here uses MySQL's InnoDB syntax and semantics; adjust accordingly for other brands.